# Make strings of latitude and longitude Data accessible as CLLocation Coordinates in various views and create a Map-route?

Tags: swift, type-conversion, coordinates, mapkit, cllocation

I have two strings that represent latitude and longitude Data of a route. In total they have around 900 entries each. I'd like to convert them to CLLocation Coordinates and then use these Coordinates to create the route as a Map polyline-overlay in a different view.

So. I'm especially interested in two issues:

- convert the strings into coordinates
- make the coordinates accessible by different views (maybe EnvironmentObject?)

For the conversion I tried this so far:

```
import SwiftUI
import Foundation
import CoreLocation
import MapKit

struct TrackData2: View {

let track01_lat = "29.0228176937071,29.022820134536,29.0228225788423"

let track01_long = "4.43144629937264,4.43144455316597,4.43144281824249"

var body: some View {
    var lat = track01_lat.components(separatedBy: ",")
    var long = track01_long.components(separatedBy: ",")

    let latitude = Double(lat)
    let longitude = Double(long)

    let coordinate:CLLocation = CLLocation(latitude: latitude, longitude: longitude)
}
}
```

But I get an error for Double(): "No exact matches in call to initializer". Any tipps on that?

Comment: have a look at: https://developer.apple.com/tutorials/swiftui

Answer (score 0):

You've got an array of numbers as strings so you have to do:

```
    let latStrings = track01_lat.components(separatedBy: ",")
    let lonStrings = track01_long.components(separatedBy: ",")
    
    if latStrings.count != lonStrings.count {
        // counts don't match
    }
    
    for i in 0..<latStrings.count {
        if let latitude = Double(latStrings[i]),
            let longitude = Double(lonStrings[i]) {
            let coordinate = CLLocation(latitude: latitude, longitude: longitude)
            
            // use the coordinate
        }
    }
```

Comment: Thanks a lot! But with the for-loop I get an error "Closure containing control flow statement cannot be used with result builder 'ViewBuilder'". I need to use the coordinates in the View in order to draw the path. Is there a workaround?

Comment: yes move the logic into a computed var that returns the array of locations. You really don't want to be creating objects like CLLocations inside SwiftUI's body though so if you can work with CLLocationCoordinate2D structs that would be better.